# Issue with google calendar on android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I try to read from google calendar on android, so i download and install the google client api follow the instruction on [instruction](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/java_client_lib.html)
I use the sample code from the tutorial website.

```
try {
         CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("demo-vibration-1");

         myService.setUserCredentials(account, password);
         // Send the request and print the response
         URL feedUrl = new URL(
               "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
         Log.v(TAG, "Calendar1");
         CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl,
               CalendarFeed.class);
         Log.v(TAG, "Calendar2");
         for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
            CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
            Log.v(TAG, entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {[syntax="java"][/syntax]
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

It compiles and run but throw a parserConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException on

```
CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl,
               CalendarFeed.class);
```

It fail on android simulate device, but if I run the code on a regular java project it works just fine. I included all the related gdata jar file into my project build path.
Is there anyone run into the same problem?

following is the exception trace
01-10 22:06:56.231: WARN/System.err(379): com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http:/xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
01-10 22:06:56.241: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:708)
01-10 22:06:56.241: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:576)
01-10 22:06:56.241: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.parseAtom(BaseFeed.java:867)
01-10 22:06:56.241: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:68)
01-10 22:06:56.251: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:39)
01-10 22:06:56.251: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.CharacterParser.parse(CharacterParser.java:100)
01-10 22:06:56.251: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.XmlInputParser.parse(XmlInputParser.java:52)
01-10 22:06:56.251: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:66)
01-10 22:06:56.251: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:34)
01-10 22:06:56.261: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2165)
01-10 22:06:56.261: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098)
01-10 22:06:56.261: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1136)
01-10 22:06:56.261: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
01-10 22:06:56.261: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:638)
01-10 22:06:56.261: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
01-10 22:06:56.271: WARN/System.err(379):     at eclipse.pratice.android.calendartest.calendartest.onCreate(calendartest.java:29)
01-10 22:06:56.271: WARN/System.err(379):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-10 22:06:56.271: WARN/System.err(379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-10 22:06:56.271: WARN/System.err(379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-10 22:06:56.271: WARN/System.err(379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-10 22:06:56.271: WARN/System.err(379):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-10 22:06:56.281: WARN/System.err(379):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 22:06:56.281: WARN/System.err(379):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-10 22:06:56.281: WARN/System.err(379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-10 22:06:56.281: WARN/System.err(379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 22:06:56.291: WARN/System.err(379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-10 22:06:56.291: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-10 22:06:56.291: WARN/System.err(379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-10 22:06:56.291: WARN/System.err(379):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 22:06:56.291: WARN/System.err(379): Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http:/xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities